# WebRequest fails to download large files (~ 1 GB) properly

Tags: c#, file, web, download, webrequest

I am attempting to download a large file from a public URL. It seemed to work fine at first but 1 / 10 computers seem to timeout. My initial attempt was to use `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` but because it would never complete I fell back to using `WebRequest.Create` and read the response streams directly.

My first version of using `WebRequest.Create` found the same problem as `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync`. The operation times out and the file does not complete.

My next version added retries if the download times out. Here is were it gets weird. The download does eventually finish with 1 retry to finish up the last 7092 bytes. So the file is downloaded with exactly the same size BUT the file is corrupt and differs from the source file. Now I would expect the corruption to be in the last 7092 bytes but this is not the case.

Using BeyondCompare I have found that there are 2 chunks of bytes missing from the corrupt file totalling up to the missing 7092 bytes! This missing bytes are at `1CA49FF0` and `1E31F380`, way way before the download times out and is restarted.

What could possibly be going on here? Any hints on how to track down this problem further?

Here is the code in question.

```
public void DownloadFile(string sourceUri, string destinationPath)
{
    //roughly based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269607/how-to-programmatically-download-a-large-file-in-c-sharp
    //not using WebClient.DownloadFileAsync as it seems to stall out on large files rarely for unknown reasons.

    using (var fileStream = File.Open(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    {
        long totalBytesToReceive = 0;
        long totalBytesReceived = 0;
        int attemptCount = 0;
        bool isFinished = false;

        while (!isFinished)
        {
            attemptCount += 1;

            if (attemptCount > 10)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Too many attempts to download. Aborting.");
            }

            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceUri);

                request.Proxy = null;//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754333/why-is-this-webrequest-code-slow/935728#935728
                _log.AddInformation("Request #{0}.", attemptCount);

                //continue downloading from last attempt.
                if (totalBytesReceived != 0)
                {
                    _log.AddInformation("Request resuming with range: {0} , {1}", totalBytesReceived, totalBytesToReceive);
                    request.AddRange(totalBytesReceived, totalBytesToReceive);
                }

                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    _log.AddInformation("Received response. ContentLength={0} , ContentType={1}", response.ContentLength, response.ContentType);

                    if (totalBytesToReceive == 0)
                    {
                        totalBytesToReceive = response.ContentLength;
                    }

                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        _log.AddInformation("Beginning read of response stream.");
                        var buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        while (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            totalBytesReceived += bytesRead;
                            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        }

                        _log.AddInformation("Finished read of response stream.");
                    }
                }

                _log.AddInformation("Finished downloading file.");
                isFinished = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.AddInformation("Response raised exception ({0}). {1}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the log output from the corrupt download:

```
Request #1.
Received response. ContentLength=939302925 , ContentType=application/zip
Beginning read of response stream.
Response raised exception (System.Net.WebException). The operation has timed out.
Request #2.
Request resuming with range: 939295833 , 939302925
Received response. ContentLength=7092 , ContentType=application/zip
Beginning read of response stream.
Finished read of response stream.
Finished downloading file.
```

Comment: I could think two things on top of my head. a) Increase your timeout for large files (if possible)   b) could your encoding and decoding of the data getting corrupted? I had this problem on a different project I once had. Try to encode it using UTF-8

Comment: It should not be an encoding issue, it is a binary blob (zip file).

Comment: Sounds to me you are trying to debug a server bug on the wrong end of the wire.

Comment: Hans, it looks like you are correct. We managed to recreate the problem (corrupt files missing bytes) by downloading using a Chrome.

Comment: +1 for solving a completely unrelated problem I was having by posting your full `DownloadFile` method.

Comment: Why are you retrying at all? Simply disable the timeout. For long running downloads there is no point in timing out, you don't *want* a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

this is the method I usually use, it hasn't failed me so far for the same kind of loading you need. Try using my code to change yours up a bit and see if that helps.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(localFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(localFolder);   
}


try
{
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Path.Combine(uri, filename));
    httpRequest.Method = "GET";

    // if the URI doesn't exist, exception gets thrown here...
    using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (FileStream localFileStream = 
                new FileStream(Path.Combine(localFolder, filename), FileMode.Create))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                long totalBytesRead = 0;
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    localFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{        
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the timeout settings.  There seem to be two possible timeout issues:

- Client-side timeout - try changing the timeouts in WebClient.  I find for large file downloads sometimes I need to do that.
- Server-side timeout - try changing the timeout on the server.  You can validate this is the problem using another client, e.g. PostMan

Answer (score 0):

For me your method on how to read the file by buffering looks very weird.
Maybe the problem is, that you do

```
while(bytesRead > 0)
```

What if, for some reason, the stream doesnt return any bytes at some point but it is still not yet finished downloading, then it would exit the loop and never come back. You should get the Content-Length, and increment a variable totalBytesReceived by bytesRead. Finally you change the loop to

```
while(totalBytesReceived < ContentLength)
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate buffer size bigger than expected file size .

byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[65536];

so that , if the file is 1GiB in size, you allocate a 1 GiB buffer, and then you try to fill the whole buffer in one call. This filling may return fewer bytes but you've still allocated the whole buffer. Note that the maximum length of a single array in .NET is a 32-bit number which means that even if you recompile your program for 64bit and actually have enough memory available.