# How can i do a Google search and display the results as a list of URL's?

Tags: c#, list, url, search

I'm trying to make a program in c# that searches Google and displays the results as a list of URL's.

I'm not sure that I can even make an application to search anything on Google help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you even googled it... come on! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12273/Google-Parser

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question discussions may solve your problem in some extent if you will give some effort.[Deserializing JSON using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521239/deserializing-json-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can do 100 free searches against the Google search API per day.  Which I think is exactly what you want.  More information on that here - https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: No that's not what I meant but thanks for answering.