# deserialize the following json response in c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Can someone please help me deserialize the following **JSON** string in C#:

```
{"legend_size": 1, 
"data": {"series": ["2013-02-05", "2013-02-06", "2013-02-07", "2013-02-08", "2013-02-09", "2013-02-10", "2013-02-11", "2013-02-12", "2013-02-13", "2013-02-14"],  "values": 
  {"CampaignHit": {"2013-02-14": 0, "2013-02-13": 0, "2013-02-12": 0, "2013-02-11": 0, "2013-02-10": 0, "2013-02-08": 11, "2013-02-05": 0, "2013-02-07": 14, "2013-02-06": 0, "2013-02-09": 0}}}}
```

I having problems with the `CampaignHit` part. I am not able to deserialize it.

Here are the classes I created:

```
public class ExportedData
{
    public string legend_size { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }

}

public class Data
{
    public string[] series { get; set; }
    public Values values { get; set; }
}

public class Values
{
    public CampaignHit CampaignHit { get; set; }
}

public class CampaignHit
{
    public CampaignData[] data { get; set; }

}

public class CampaignData
{
    public object first { get; set; }
    public object second { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code to deserialize json:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExportedData>(jsonResponse);
```

The data part is null. How do I change the `CampaignHit` class so that data is not null after deserialization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521239/deserializing-json-using-c-sharp)

Comment: "I having problems" doesn't tell us anything about what's wrong. Please be more specific, and describe what's happening, if you want us to be able to figure out your issue.

Comment: Don't post code as comments, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using Newtonsoft.Json :

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(@"{
'legend_size': 1,
'data': {
    'series': [
        '2013-02-05', '2013-02-06', '2013-02-07', '2013-02-08', '2013-02-09', '2013-02-10', '2013-02-11', '2013-02-12', '2013-02-13', '2013-02-14'
    ],
    'values': {
        'CampaignHit': {
            '2013-02-14': 0,
            '2013-02-13': 0,
            '2013-02-12': 0,
            '2013-02-11': 0,
            '2013-02-10': 0,
            '2013-02-08': 11,
            '2013-02-05': 0,
            '2013-02-07': 14,
            '2013-02-06': 0,
            '2013-02-09': 0
        }
    }
}
}");

var  campaignHit = jObject["data"]["values"]["CampaignHit"];

Dictionary<string,int> campaignHitDic = new Dictionary<string,int>();

foreach(JProperty c in campaignHit){
campaignHitDic.Add(c.Name,(int)c.Value);
}
```