# How to Parse an example string in C#

Tags: c#, json, string, parsing

I have this string

```
[
    {
        "url_short":"http:\/\/sample.com\/8jyKHv",
        "url_long":"http:\/\/www.sample.com\/",
        "type":0
    }
]
```

What I want is to get `http:\/\/sample.com\/8jyKHv` and translate it to

```
http://sample.com/8jyKHv
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You have 2 options here. Either you treat this as a string and use substring and replace. Either you treat this as a JSON and do a deserialize into a class object. Both will yield to the desired result

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260631/convert-json-into-class-object-in-c-sharp for the JSON deserialize method -- Which I recommend over the substring solution

Comment: Yeah, strongly recommend the JSON way, not the string/substring/replace method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON way is for sure recommended, but cant tell much about it. Here's the alternative way with regex:

```
Regex rgxUrl = new Regex("\"url_short\":\"(.*?)\",\"");
Match mUrl = rgxUrl.Match(yourString);

string url = Regex.Replace(mUrl.Groups[1].Value, @"\", "");
```

Comment: must be Regex.Replace(mUrl.Groups[1].Value, @"\\", "");

Comment: @AJB nope. `@` is already escapting the string. Either `"\\"` or `@"\"`.

Answer (score 4):

This string is JSON.

You can parse it by using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RootObject
{
    public string url_short { get; set; }
    public string url_long { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        string j = "[{\"url_short\":\"http:\\/\\/sample.com\\/8jyKHv\",\"url_long\":\"http:\\/\\/www.sample.com\\/\",\"type\":0}]";

        List<RootObject> ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(j);

        Console.WriteLine(ro[0].url_short);                 
    }    
}
```

Response:

> http://sample.com/8jyKHv

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Create a class like below

Note : you can use Paste Special option in visual studio to generate all the classes related to the JSON

Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json As Classes

it will create all the classes related to the JSON

```
    public class url_details
    {
        public string url_short { get; set; }
        public string url_long { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
    }


    public List<url_details> json_deserialized()
    {
        string json = "[{\"url_short\":\"http:\\/\\/sample.com\\/8jyKHv\",\"url_long\":\"http:\\/\\/www.sample.com\\/\",\"type\":0}]";

        List<url_details> items = new List<url_details>();
        items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<url_details>>(json);

        return items;
    }
```

And you can access the element like below

```
   List<url_details> obj = json_deserialized();

   string url_short = obj[0].url_short;
```

Answer (score 2):

The string is a JSON string so you can create a class to get the values like this

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string url_short
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string url_long
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

After this class you can get the data like this

```
string json = "[{"url_short":"http:\/\/sample.com\/8jyKHv","url_long":"http:\/\/www.sample.com\/","type":0}]";
List<Rootobject> ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(json);
string ururl = ro[0].Propert1[0].url_short;
```

Comment: Removal of \ is obsolete because after deserialization it has gone. Your json sample string is wrong (missing the "\"). See http://json.org for specs

Comment: One error left: The json contains an array of objects ;o)