# JSON to c# fail to deserialize

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, deserialization

How can I deserialize Jobject to a List ? I'm receiving a JSON from kendo-ui toolbar button "create", and I can't control the dispatch of the data. I can only set the format. Now I've got JSON type set.

```
create: 
{
    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "CreateContacts",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json"  
}
```

in my c# controller I tried to receive json as a string but failed.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateContacts(JObject jobject)
{
}
```

If I set parameters as Jobject I get data but I don't know how to deserialize  it to a List. I tried to create a class with same fields as in the json, but I get null when make deserialize. What can be done here? THX!

[image]

Comment: refer this link I have answer for like this question it might help you to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607277/how-to-parse-an-example-string-in-c-sharp/38608187#38608187

Comment: try adding `type: "json"` to `create` property