# Read and parse Json on c# and get specific values

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm trying to parse a Json that contains a lot of objects.

.json look like this:
:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "prices" : [
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "4X4 Car",
      "price" : "7.87",
      "created_at" : 1472587613
    },
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "Yellow Car",
      "price" : "27.75",
      "created_at" : 1472519899
    }
```

[...] etc

and I just want to get the price of specific market hash name. How can I do that?

I have got this atm

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
      public class MarketHandler
        {
            //Methods
            public MarketHandler updatePrices()
            {
                var json = File.ReadAllText("PriceSkins.json");
                currentPrices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
                return this;
            }

            public Data currentPrices { get; set; }
            public class Data
            {
                public Response response { get; set; }
            }

            public class Response
            {
                public string status { get; set; }
                public Price prices { get; set; }
            }

            public class Price
            {
                public string market_hash_name { get; set; }
                public string price { get; set; }
                public int created_at { get; set; }
            }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Also, I don't see the code where you actually try to get the value.

Comment: Your model doesn't match your JSON at the moment - you don't have a *single* price, you have an *array* of prices. (I'd urge you do follow .NET naming conventions and use attributes to specify the JSON representation, btw.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this, place your JSON some where else on your system and load the JSON like below

```
 Rootobject ro = new Rootobject();
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("text.json"));
 string jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 ro = ser.Deserialize<Rootobject>(jsonString);
```

Before that you have to create the classes like below these classes are matching your JSON, already I have answer similar this question [here you can  cehck how to create classes for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607277/how-to-parse-an-example-string-in-c-sharp/38608187#38608187) easily

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Price[] prices { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public string market_hash_name { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public int created_at { get; set; }
}
```

After that,from the instance of the Rootobject(ro) you can access the price like below

```
Price[] price_list = ro.prices;
```